# Apache Flink TumblingProcessingTimeWindows firing at the wrong time

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

May I know what I'm doing here. I have set window time as **20** secs. but my process is firing at odd intervals.
[image]

I'm applying keyBy before window and my key's are like A, B, C.

```
KafkaSource<Event> source = KafkaSource.<Event>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                //.setTopics("events", "event1")
                .setTopics("events")
                .setGroupId("my-group")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(Event.class, "http://localhost:8081"))
                .build();

        DataStream<Event> eventStream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source")
                .name("event-stream");

        DataStream<Event> keyed =  eventStream.keyBy((KeySelector<Event, String>) Event::getType)
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20)))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Event, Event, String, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(String s, ProcessWindowFunction<Event, Event, String, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<Event> elements, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
                        System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
                    }
                });

        keyed.print();
```

Comment: Could you please share with us the related piece of code as code?

Comment: Hi, I have added it now.

Comment: One oddity is that your `ProcessWindowFunction` isn't emitting any results (never calls the `Collector`), so the `keyed.print()` statement won't be generating any results. Is that what you want?

Comment: From what i understood from the windows, process method should fire every 20 secs(window time). but isn't, it is firing at the wrong interval.Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: Can someone help me understand what am i doing here ?

Comment: Have you tried to print out `context.window().getStart()` and `context.window().getEnd()`?

Comment: KEY: Visit,CURRENT TIME: 2022-05-12 12:47:50,CONTEXT START TIME:2022-05-12 12:47:45,CONTEXT END TIME:2022-05-12 12:47:50 ,RECORDS: 41544
KEY: Login,CURRENT TIME: 2022-05-12 12:47:51,CONTEXT START TIME:2022-05-12 12:47:45,CONTEXT END TIME:2022-05-12 12:47:50 ,RECORDS: 41494
KEY: Sign Up Completed,CURRENT TIME: 2022-05-12 12:47:53,CONTEXT START TIME:2022-05-12 12:47:45,CONTEXT END TIME:2022-05-12 12:47:50 ,RECORDS: 41575

Comment: context.window().getStart() and end is correct but the time im printing inside process is not in sync. wondering why and how is that.

process should be called at the end of context.window().getEnd() time, not sure why is there a big gap

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem by pulling out Kafka from the picture? So, did you try to create `Event`s manually and create a `DataStream` from them via the [`fromElements` or `fromCollection`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/overview/#collection-data-sources) API calls?

Comment: Also why did you use `WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks()`? Don't you want to use even time windows?

Comment: As far as i understood, water marks are for event time windows where we specify the time parameter in the event to be used to control window time. Im using ProcessTime Windows should work with the system time.

Answer (score 0):

The window is for a keyed stream, so there will be multiple windows for different keys. When the windows are triggered(here it is every 20 sec), multiple windows for different keys will be handled by your *process* function, which will print out a date string.

As there are multiple windows being processed, we can see multiple outputs. They are actually from multiple windows for different keys. We can also see a group of outputs in every 20 sec if Flink can print all the window outputs. If there are too many keys, probably you cannot see the interval boundary through console output.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. There are only 3 keys. I assume my output should be like : 

2022-05-10 03:00:10 
2022-05-10 03:00:10
2022-05-10 03:00:10
2022-05-10 03:00:30 
2022-05-10 03:00:30
2022-05-10 03:00:30


But it is like



2022-05-10 03:00:52
2022-05-10 03:00:52
2022-05-10 03:00:52
2022-05-10 03:00:57 
2022-05-10 03:00:57
2022-05-10 03:00:57

Which I do not understand.

Comment: Can you add more info in the print to include the key? Like: key1 YYYY-MM-DD...

Comment: sure
KEY: Login ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:22:40 ,RECORDS: 66751
KEY: Sign Up Completed ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:22:40 ,RECORDS: 66738
KEY: Visit ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:22:40 ,RECORDS: 66196
KEY: Login ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:22:50 ,RECORDS: 56150
KEY: Visit ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:22:50 ,RECORDS: 55642
KEY: Sign Up Completed ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:22:50 ,RECORDS: 56185
KEY: Login ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:23:20 ,RECORDS: 28380
KEY: Sign Up Completed ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:23:20 ,RECORDS: 28633
KEY: Visit ,TIME: 2022-05-11 10:23:20 ,RECORDS: 28370

After 22:50, It has skipped to 23:20

Comment: Emmm, another thing is, what's the parallelism of the windows operator? There may be multiple tasks running in parallel which will make the output a bit confusing.

Comment: Hi, I have set it to 1 
 env.setParallelism(1);